# An explanation for BNF rule

Tags: mysql, parsing, bison, yacc

I'm investigating the mysql's SQL parser at the moment.

And here is the interesting thing I have noticed and cannot explain:

(in `sql_yacc.yy`)

```
predicate:
        ...
        | bit_expr BETWEEN_SYM bit_expr AND_SYM predicate
          {
            $$= new (YYTHD->mem_root) Item_func_between($1,$3,$5);
            if ($$ == NULL)
              MYSQL_YYABORT;
          }
```

The same is on the [Expression Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/expressions.html) page:

```
predicate:
  ...
  | bit_expr [NOT] BETWEEN bit_expr AND predicate
```

That means that

```
foo BETWEEN 1 AND bar BETWEEN 1 AND 2
```

query syntactically correct, while it makes no sense at all.

My question: what this could be used for? What would we miss if used

```
bit_expr [NOT] BETWEEN bit_expr AND bit_expr
```

instead?

## <strike>LOL</strike> (not a LOL anymore actually)

this query executes **WITHOUT** errors:

```
select * from users where id between 1 and id between 1 and 10;
// returns row with id = 1

select * from users where id between 2 and id between 2 and 10;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

(update is added here) ... and actually it **is** expected.

Presumably it converts the second expression straight to `0` or `1` and uses it as an operand.

**UPD**:

I've filed a bug - http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69208

<strike>It's definitely not an expected syntax at all</strike>

**UPD 2**: so looks like it's just a minor typo that doesn't change a parser behaviour at all (well, to be clear it makes it unnoticeable slower for a common `BETWEEN` expression).

Comment: I would ask that on some mysql developer's list....

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch: sometimes stackoverflow wonders, if I'll be still curious and not answered here in several days - I'll ask on mail list indeed :-)

Comment: Note that this is a production language, but it isn't BNF.

Comment: @EJP: indeed, BNF-like though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your analysis is basically correct:

```
foo BETWEEN 1 AND bar BETWEEN 1 AND 2
```

is parsed as:

```
foo BETWEEN 1 AND (bar BETWEEN 1 AND 2)
```

and the second (parenthesized) predicate will presumably evaluate to either 0 or 1 (for false or true).  Therefore, if `bar` is not between 1 and 2, the set of selected values from `foo` will be empty (because `foo BETWEEN 1 AND 0` is a shorthand for `foo >= 1 AND f <= 0` and there are no values for which that is true, even allowing for NULLs).  Contrariwise, if `bar` is between 1 and 2, then the set of selected values from `foo` will be the set where `foo1 equals 1.

And alternative question to your "what would you lose if you replaced the 'predicate' term with 'bit_expr'?" might be "would you gain anything if you replaced the 'bit_expr' with 'predicate'?"

Without a careful scrutiny of the complete grammar (or, at least, scrutiny of the parts referenced by `bit_expr` and `predicate`, and possibly a review of places where `bit_expr` and `predicate` are used), it is hard to know the answer to either question.

Comment: Yep, I've filed a bug - let's see what they will reply (at least we can only guess until someone from dev team responds)